# Feathers auth Invalid login

Tags: feathersjs

I'm try to use local authentication, but get error message "Invalid Login".

1. I send 'local' auth from client. Received data on server

```
{ strategy: 'local',
      email: 'email@gmail.com',
      password: '123' },
    { query: {},
      provider: 'socketio',
      headers: {},
      session: {},
      cookies: {} }
```

In authentication.js

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  const config = app.get('authentication');

  // Set up authentication with the secret
  app.configure(authentication(config));
  app.configure(jwt());
  app.configure(local());

  app.configure(oauth2(Object.assign({
    name: 'auth0',
    Strategy: Auth0Strategy
  }, config.auth0)));

  app.service('authentication').hooks({
    before: {
      create: [
        (data)=>{console.log('auth',data.arguments)},
        authentication.hooks.authenticate(config.strategies),
      ],
      remove: [
        authentication.hooks.authenticate('jwt')
      ]
    }
  });
};
```

2. Server find record in database and return query result

```
{ id: 1,
         email: 'email@gmail.com',
         password:
          '$2a$13$t2XZsqu/0t5jKSdbRUyZTOVOoZJVtiha3sN/Z8N0O190Z0DUJj70O',
         auth0Id: null,
         isVerified: null,
         verifyToken: 'string',
         verifyExpires: null,
         resetToken: 'string',
         resetExpires: null,
         createdAt: 2019-04-14T22:04:52.000Z,
         updatedAt: 2019-04-14T22:04:52.000Z }
```

3. After that it try to compare hahs of passwords, but hash of received password not equals to password in query result. Received password combine with current time  in result hash.

How to use local auth in feathers?

UPD

configuraions from default.json

```
"authentication": {
    "secret": "my secret key here",
    "strategies": [
      "jwt",
      "local"
    ],
    "path": "/authentication",
    "service": "users",
    "jwt": {
      "header": {
        "typ": "access"
      },
      "audience": "https://yourdomain.com",
      "subject": "anonymous",
      "issuer": "feathers",
      "algorithm": "HS256",
      "expiresIn": "1d"
    },
    "local": {
      "entity": "user",
      "usernameField": "email",
      "passwordField": "password"
    },
    "auth0": {
      "clientID": "your auth0 client id",
      "clientSecret": "your auth0 client secret",
      "successRedirect": "/",
      "domain": "mydomain.auth0.com",
      "scopes": [
        "profile"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Just or the sake of curiosity, why are you sending the authentication strategy as `local` if you are trying to authenticate using `OAuth`?

Comment: I think, if I use app.configure(local()); I add a local auth method.

Comment: If local not added, I get BadRequest: Authentication strategy 'local' is not registered

Comment: ave you tried the OAuth strategy?

Comment: How does this affect the local auth?

Comment: When you say "Received password combine with current time in result hash", does that mean you are using a hook to change the way the password is hashed?

The local strategy uses bcrypt to hash and compare the provided password. If you are changing the way the password is hashed, that's the reason you are getting the error.

Comment: I do not change the standard hook. I looked in '@ feathersjs / authentication' and saw (with help console.log(password)) that the password hash was different for each call. As result 'Invalid Password'

Answer (score 0):

Actually the bcrypt(used by feathers internally for hashing) is using salts to hash our passwords, that's why you are getting different different results on each time for the same string.